# Flip ggplot y-axis for bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph that plots rank, where lower values are better. I want larger bars to correspond to smaller values, so the "best" groups in the data receive more visual weight.

Reprex:

```
dat = data.frame("Group" = c(rep("Best",50),
                             rep("Middle",50),
                             rep("Worst",50)
                             ),
                 "Rank" = c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.5),
                            rnorm(n = 50, mean = 2.5, sd = 0.5),
                            rnorm(n = 50, mean = 3.5, sd = 0.5)
                            )
                 )

    tibdat = as_tibble(dat) %>%
      group_by(Group) %>%
      summarise(Mean_Rank = mean(Rank,na.rm=T))

# creates simple rightside up bar graph
  
    ggplot(data = tibdat, mapping = aes(Group, Mean_Rank, fill = Group)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:4), limits = c(1,4),  oob = scales::squish)

# my attempt below, simply reversing the breaks and limits
    
    ggplot(data = tibdat, mapping = aes(Group, Mean_Rank, fill = Group)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(4:1), limits = c(4,1),  oob = scales::squish)
```

The graphing code at the end does succeed in flipping the axis, but the data disappears (the bars are not plotted).

Note that I do *not* want the graphs to originate from the top, which scale_y_reverse can achieve. I want the bars to originate from the bottom, at the y = 4 line (or below).

How is this achieved?

Edit: Added image below to show the original bar graph that works but is wrong.

[image: Graph that works but is not ideal]

Answer (score 1):

I just transformed the labels. I don't know if that's what you searched.

```
ggplot(data = tibdat, mapping = aes(Group, Mean_Rank, fill = Group)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:4), limits = c(1,4), oob = scales::squish, labels = function(x) 5 - x)
```

With another trick in the aes argument I think you can arrive to the wanted result. Maybe someone better than me knows a clean way to do it.

```
ggplot(data = tibdat, mapping = aes(Group, 5 - Mean_Rank, fill = Group)) +
geom_col() +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:4), limits = c(1,4),  oob = scales::squish, labels = function(x) 5 - x)
```

And here is the result :
[image: plot_from_4]

Comment: This still leave the Worst group with the largest bar. I'm trying to make the bar for Best group the largest, spanning from 4 (at bottom) to 1.5 (near top). The Worst bar should be smallest, spanning from 4 to 3.5.

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood a little. You can go with 5 - Mean_Rank in aes. I know it's kind of a chead trick but it seems to work. I edit my answer. Let me know if that's what you searched.

Comment: Yes this does work and will serve my purpose, thanks for your help! However it does make me uneasy to change the data itself rather than the axis/graph details.